# apache solr for translated documents indexing

Tags: solr

does Apache solr allow this:

The possibility of returning to the user, in addition to the document translated into French, the original text as well as the contexts of use in the original text?

**the documents to be indexed is a pdf files.**

**ُEdit: Add example**

i have the original document `doc_eng.pdf` and the translated document `doc_fr.pdf`

when the `doc_fr.pdf` is return in a query response i want to be able to to get `doc_eng.pdf` also with the context (highlighting) if it is possible

**My suggestion**

1- map `doc_fr.pdf` and `doc_eng.pdf` to the same id (if this can be done) and add a boolean field isOriginal =true|false .

2- use nested documents (but i dont get how this will work with pdf files)

Comment: You'll have to add the translation yourself (and thus, also the context matching between what has been translated into what); Solr does not include any translation mechanism by default.

Comment: thanks, yes i did that but i ask for the relation between the original file and the translated file.

Comment: Yes, that's something you'll have to add metadata for yourself - i.e. which terms / sentences matches which translated content. If you _do_ have that metadata, then include it mapped id in the stored text, and use it to highlight both sides of the content - both the original and the translated, and strip the metadata when displaying content ot the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, solr can do this. I would suggest you to use `apache tika mechanism`

> Solr can identify languages and map text to language-specific fields during indexing using the langid UpdateRequestProcessor.

Solr supports two implementations of this feature:

> [Tika’s language detection feature](http://tika.apache.org/0.10/detection.html)

> [LangDetect language detection](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection
> https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/language-analysis.html)

[Refer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/detecting-languages-during-indexing.html)

[Translator](https://tika.apache.org/1.7/api/org/apache/tika/language/translate/class-use/Translator.html)

Comment: That seems right to me, I'm going to try it. Can you look at the update i add to the question.

Comment: @elouanesbg Yes, Comment from Matslindh is the right solution for the other question.